Removing whitespace within matplotlib plot with subplots
Problem
When generating the following plot, I am not able to remove the white frame that appears around each graph (note: colors were changed to make the problem more obviously visible).

Is there any way to remove this unwanted effect?
Attempt so far
I've been looking for solutions, but haven't found anything that seems to work. I suspect that there's something annoying that Seaborn is doing. Here are the links that I found on SO, in case people want to know where I've looked.

Removing the white border around an image when using matplotlib without saving the image
How to remove white lines when plotting multiple subplots in Matplotlib?
Remove white border when using subplot and imshow in python (Matplotlib)
Eliminate white space between subplots in a matplotlib figure

But none of these seem applicable. In particular, the whitespace is somehow within the plot rather than on its boundary.
Code to reproduce figure (MRE)
It might stretch the "minimal" part of MRE, but here's code that produces the above figure.
## imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

##produce dataframes
results = pd.DataFrame(
{'cat_1': {0: -0.03200000000000003,
  1: -0.040000000000000036,
  2: -0.030400000000000205,
  3: -0.024800000000000155,
  4: 2.2880000000000003},
 'cat_2': {0: 0.13839999999999986,
  1: 0.14880000000000004,
  2: 0.14880000000000004,
  3: 0.13759999999999994,
  4: 7.3991999999999996},
 'cat_3': {0: 0.1719999999999997,
  1: 0.15039999999999987,
  2: 0.1823999999999999,
  3: 0.16559999999999953,
  4: 12.720000000000002},
 'cat_4': {0: 0.2967999999999993,
  1: 0.6991999999999994,
  2: 0.735199999999999,
  3: 0.7607999999999997,
  4: 23.2432},
 'label': {0: 'label_1',
  1: 'label_2',
  2: 'label_3',
  3: 'label_4',
  4: 'label_5'}}
)

relative_results = pd.DataFrame(
{'cat_1': {0: -2.123424021234242,
  1: -2.6542800265428026,
  2: -2.0172528201725415,
  3: -1.6456536164565463,
  4: 151.82481751824818},
 'cat_2': {0: 6.275505577219545,
  1: 6.747075360478827,
  2: 6.747075360478827,
  3: 6.2392309785072975,
  4: 335.5037634896164},
 'cat_3': {0: 6.359535606004574,
  1: 5.56089625083191,
  2: 6.744065665902532,
  3: 6.122901722990442,
  4: 470.30984249057167},
 'cat_4': {0: 5.825318940137375,
  1: 13.723258096172705,
  2: 14.429833169774268,
  3: 14.932286555446508,
  4: 456.1962708537782},
 'label': {0: 'label_1',
  1: 'label_2',
  2: 'label_3',
  3: 'label_4',
  4: 'label_5'}}
)

baseline = pd.Series(
{'cat_1': 1.507,
 'cat_2': 2.2054,
 'cat_3': 2.7046,
 'cat_4': 5.095,
 'label': 'label_0'}
)

## functions to manipulate second y-axis
def get_new_bounds(ax1, baseline, col):
    a,b = ax1.get_ybound()
    return a*baseline[col]/100, b*baseline[col]/100

def get_new_ticks(ax1, baseline, col):
    ticks  = ax1.get_yticks()
    return ticks*baseline[col] / 100

## custom settings
rc={"axes.facecolor":"#b3edff", 
    "figure.facecolor":"#b3edff",
    # "grid.color":"#ffbb33",
    "grid.color":"#202020",
    "grid.linewidth":0.3,
    "lines.linewidth":0.7,
    "lines.markersize":20, 
    "font.family":"Calibri"}
sns.set_theme(font_scale = 1.25, rc = rc)

## plot figure
cols = [f"cat_{i}" for i in range(1,5)]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2, 
                        figsize = (20,10), 
                        sharex = False, 
                        sharey=True)

for ax, col in zip(axs.ravel(), cols):

    sns.pointplot(  
                    data = relative_results, 
                    x = "label",
                    y = col,
                    ax = ax,
                    markersize=7)
    ax.set_xlabel("")
    ax.set_ylabel("")
    ax.set_title(col)
    ax.axhline(0, ls='--', color = 'k')

# note: getting rid of the second y-axis doesn't solve the problem
for i, ax, col in zip(range(4), axs.ravel(), cols):

    if i >= 2:
        ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    # if i%2 == 1:
    #     ax2.set_ylabel("(ms) change in latency")
    ax2.set_yticks(get_new_ticks(ax, baseline, col))
    ax2.set_ybound(*get_new_bounds(ax, baseline, col))
    ax2.grid(False)

fig.text(-1.3, 1, '(%) change', 
        ha='center', va='center', rotation='vertical', transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize = "xx-large")
fig.text(1.15, 1, '(unit) change', 
        ha='center', va='center', rotation='vertical', transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize = "xx-large")
fig.supxlabel("x-axis label", fontsize = "xx-large")
fig.suptitle("Title", fontsize = "xx-large")

plt.show()


Placing " [axis.spines[border].set_visible(False) for border in borders] "   in both the for loops seems to do it.  borders = ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right']

Or ax.set_frame_on(False), and  ax2.set_frame_on(False) in the for loops.

@DavidG Thank you! That works like a charm. If you leave an answer I'd be happy to accept it

There is also seaborn's despine function: sns.despine(top=True, right=True, left=True, bottom=True). By default, it applies to all the axes of the current figure.
